# MySQL event not working (insert statement)

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I am using `PHP` to execute the `SQL query`, the event can be created but no random data is inserted into the database. The global event scheduler is set on.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

What I try to do is to insert random data into the database every second once the event is created.

Below are my code :

```
<?php

$hostname="localhost";
$username="root";
$password='xxx';
$dbname="database";

$conn= mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else {

$query="CREATE EVENT XXX
ON SCHEDULE 
EVERY 1 SECOND
STARTS '2019-12-28 9:45:20' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO
INSERT INTO water(Id,datetime,ph1,ec1,wt1,
ph2,ec2,wt2,
ph3,ec3,wt3,
ph4,ec4,wt4) 
VALUES(NOW(),ROUND(FLOOR(21 * RAND()) / 100, 2) + 7.40,
ROUND(FLOOR(101 * RAND()) / 10, 1) + 650,
ROUND(FLOOR(21 * RAND()) / 10, 1) + 23,
ROUND(FLOOR(21 * RAND()) / 100, 2) + 7.40,
ROUND(FLOOR(101 * RAND()) / 10, 1) + 650,
ROUND(FLOOR(21 * RAND()) / 10, 1) + 23,
ROUND(FLOOR(21 * RAND()) / 100, 2) + 7.40,
ROUND(FLOOR(101 * RAND()) / 10, 1) + 650,
ROUND(FLOOR(21 * RAND()) / 10, 1) + 23,
ROUND(FLOOR(21 * RAND()) / 100, 2) + 7.40,
ROUND(FLOOR(101 * RAND()) / 10, 1) + 650,
ROUND(FLOOR(21 * RAND()) / 10, 1) + 23);";


if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
    echo "successful";
}else{
    echo ("error :". mysqli_error($conn));

}



}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is this just for educational purposes, because the exercise seems entirely futile otherwise!?!

Comment: You have specified 14 items to be inserted but only providing 13, perhaps id is auto_increment and does not need to be specified.

Comment: There is no error thrown...the event can be created successfully but no data is inserted at all @@

Comment: Ya id field is auto increment..